Using Revit Python Shell, is it possible for the print statement to output colored text?
Using Revit Python Shell, is it possible to get a print statement to print colored text?
For example,
print "An Apple is red"

where the word "Apple" prints in red.

The print keyword looks as if you were really still using Python 2.7. It's been dead for two years now; not even security upgrades. Please switch to a maintained version of Python as soon as possible.

Doesn't look like Revit supports color of stdout directly, but you can use the colorama library.
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style

# Initialize Colorama
colorama.init(autoreset=True)

# Printing "Apple" in red
print(f"An {Fore.RED}Apple{Style.RESET_ALL} is red")

